# Recommendations for visualising a directed graph in a Web UI

Tags: javascript, flash, web-applications, user-interface, components

I need to visualise a directed graph that represents the flow of data in a web application. Can anyone recommend any JavaScript or Flash solutions for this please. It must support hooking a node click event because I need to fire off an AJAX call when this happens. Can be free or commercial. The server-side technology is Java if this makes any difference.

The JProbe Call Graph is the sort of thing I have in mind:

[image: JProbe Call Graph]
<sub>(source: [javaworld.com](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/images/jw-0822-profiler9.gif))</sub>

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I like [WireIt](http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/). It's written in JavaScript and is quite versatile. And open source (MIT License)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

http://flare.prefuse.org/

Flare is an ActionScript library for creating visualizations that run in the Adobe Flash Player. From basic charts and graphs to complex interactive graphics, the toolkit supports data management, visual encoding, animation, and interaction techniques. Even better, flare features a modular design that lets developers create customized visualization techniques without having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Also give a try Google  Visualisation API and especially [Org Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#org_chart) .

Answer (score 3):

The [d3 library](http://d3js.org/) is much more versatile than the libraries mentioned above (it's also a lower-level library).

Comment: d3 looks very cool. How would you use it to make a workflow graph? I guess you'd have an array of nodes and an array of links?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [birdeye RaVis](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis) on Flash. It's open source.

Answer (score 2):

Our [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com) library is built for such things. You can see an example application at the [draw.io](http://www.draw.io) site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html). From my initial tests, it looks more than capable of making this kind of graph. It's open source (MIT or GPL2), works with jQuery, MooTools and YUI, and can use SVG, canvas or VML for rendering.