# Making a directed graph from a list of edges in javascript

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, directed-graph

I have a list of edges where the it goes from key to value

so `a => [x,y,z]` meaning `a` is connected to `x`, to `y` and to `z`

I have a long list of these and I want to visualize it, preferably with javascript.

What are some known javascript packages that will do this painlessly (input edges, output graph via javascript)

Comment: You can try to draw it yourself with `canvas`

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448319/recommendations-for-visualising-a-directed-graph-in-a-web-ui

Comment: http://arborjs.org/ could fit your bill.

Comment: Also checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646152/how-to-create-a-multiple-linked-directed-graph-with-javascript - they recommended jsPlumb (http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), the API is intuitive and does an excellent job of visualising data. Some example outputs are available [here (d3noob.org)](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-examples.html) and [here (bl.ocks.org)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

A basic walkthrough of a creating directed graph is available from d3noob.org [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try Cytoscape.js.  It is a graph analysis and visualisation library in Javascript.
http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/

It even supports edges with endpoint markers (i.e. arrows), which are useful for directed graphs.

Disclaimer: I am involved in Cytoscape.js.